# Is there a way to switch cwd by changing environment in PM2 - node.js

Tags: json, node.js, pm2

I am using PM2 to manage the execution of a couple of micro-apps on node.

**Goal:**
However I would like to be able to automatically switch settings and the `cwd` value **based on the environment** the app is executing in.

**For example:** on my local machine `CWD` should be `~/user/pm2`, while on the server it needs to be `E:\Programs\PM2`.

Is there any way to do this **using JSON config options** with PM2? Is there a better way to manage the variables for different environments?

Answer (score 1):

you can save a shell script, say `pm2_dev.sh` containing the `cd` command as first line.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /foo/bar
pm2-dev run my-app.js
```

**OR** you can add input to your script:

```
# pm2_dev.sh ~/user/pm2
```

file should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $1
pm2-dev run my-app.js
```

Comment: I was hoping for a way to use the pm2 json config file to accomplish it, but I will keep this in mind as an alternative.

Comment: it's ok, but mind that it follows the common practice of node, grunt and npm of enclose a set of provision settings under a single command/script. your best.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to change environment by shell script, you can follow [documentation way](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/):

> ```
> {   "apps" : [{
>     "script"      : "worker.js",
>     "watch"       : true,
>     "env": {
>       "NODE_ENV": "development",
>     },
>     "env_production" : {
>        "NODE_ENV": "production"
>     }   },{
>     "name"       : "api-app",
>     "script"     : "api.js",
>     "instances"  : 4,
>     "exec_mode"  : "cluster"   }] }
> ```

When running your application you should use `--env` option [as it is written here](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/#options):

> --env              specify environment to get
>   specific env variables (for JSON declaration)

Finally you can wrap configuration in a js object that conditionally returns parameters basing on current environment:

```
module.exports = (function(env){

  if( env === 'development' )
    return { folder: '~/user/pm2' };

  else if( env === 'production' )
    return { folder: 'E:\Programs\PM2' };

}(process.env.NODE_ENV));
```

Then you can require the config file and access it being sure that it returns always the correct config.